# Different line endings in JabRef on Windows and Linux

Tags: bibtex, revision-control, jabref

I'm working on a bib file using JabRef on Windows and Linux. The bib file is synchronized via a version control program.

Unfortunately, JabRef seems to save the bib file with Windows line endings (CR LF) on Windows and with Linux line endings (LF) on Linux respectively (I checked this using Vim, which displays the file format). This very annoying with revision control since JabRef will always modify the whole file instead of only a fews lines that were actually modified.

Is it possible to force JabRef to use a defined line break style? I'm using version 2.7b but also tried the current version 2.9.2.

I'm using Bazaar as version control system.

Comment: It might depend on which version control system you use. Mercurial, for example, has an extension to convert line breaks to a uniform format before commits. I would report the issue to the maintainers of JabRef.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Guido Thank you for the hint. I'm using Bazaar and Bazaar provides [EOL conversion](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.6/en/user-reference/eol-help.html). I will try this as workaround.

Comment: Regarding the _off-topic_ vote: The [help center](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) tells me that this is the right place to ask questions about software and tools related to TeX and LaTeX. In my opinion this includes JabRef.

Comment: I agree that this is on topic here. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Just wait for the next release -- see: https://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/feature-requests/857/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a feature not available in the current release of JabRef